# Twitter API removes characters to add link to original tweet

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I'm am using [LinqToTwitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) in my application to gather tweets. For testing I now retrieve some public tweets and noticed text of tweets go missing:

### Example:

Tweet in my application: 
[image: Tweet in my application] 
[Original tweet](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/796308802278748160): 
[image: Original tweet] 
Notice t.co/czD2e7Z3q1 in my application links to the original tweet and because the tweet text + t.co link would exeed the 140char limit the tweet text is shortend and ... is added.

### Code

Currently I retrive tweets using this code:

```
var srch = (from search in twitterCtx.Search
                        where search.Type == Twitter.SearchType.Search &&
                            search.Query == "twitter" &&
                            search.Count == 100 &&
                            search.GeoCode == geocode &&
                            search.IncludeEntities == true
                        select search).SingleOrDefault();
```

Is there a way I can get the original tweet text without the t.co link at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I recently added extended tweet support to LINQ to Twitter. Here's the beta on NuGet: [LINQ to Twitter v4.2.0 Beta 2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter/4.2.0-beta2).

Tip: You'll need to check the pre-release box in the VS NuGet GUI to find it.

Comment: I assume that I will need to wait for Twitter te release the extended tweet features shown on this page: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets

Comment: @MaikoKingma Most, if not all, of those changes are in effect now. In their Announcements section of the Forums, they talk more about what and when features are available: https://twittercommunity.com/c/announcements

Comment: @JoeMayo - I've installed v4.2.0 Beta 2 but I still get truncated tweets. Do I need to turn something else on? entity.FullText is also `null`

Comment: I think I found it - needed to set `TweetMode == TweetMode.Extended`

Comment: @JoeMayo does extended tweet support still display the original text (not the t.co shortened links)? I have TweetMode.Extended enabled and am still seeing t.co links in the FullText of the Status.

Comment: @BLAZORLOVER Check out the `Entities` property, it has a `UrlEntities` collection with all of the t.co links that map to the actual URL. There are also other entity types for hashtag, symbol, and user mentions. Another property, `ExtendedEntites`, has MediaEntities details too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it via the API, you will have to wait till the new changes outlined on [dev.twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets) are available.

Or, if you want an "ugly but works" solution today, you can just scrape `twitter.com/<@user>/status/tweetid` to get the full text of the tweet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know when the dev.twitter article was posted or updated?

Comment: Found this blog post from last May: https://blog.twitter.com/2016/doing-more-with-140-characters